Error Loading GLB File with Shape Keys in Babylon.js
I encounter an issue when exporting a Blender file to GLB format and loading it in Babylon.js. The error only occurs when I select all shape keys during export. If I do not select all shape keys, the issue does not arise.
Error loading model file: Unable to load from male.glb: Error in onSuccess callback RuntimeError: Unable to load from male.glb: Error in onSuccess callback
    at t [as constructor    at t [as constructor] (babylon.js:1:365631)
    at new t (error.ts:76:9)
    at p (sceneLoader.ts:1026:46)
    at _ (sceneLoader.ts:1050:21)
    at sceneLoader.ts:1075:29
(anonymous) @ test.html:75Understand this error
logger.ts:107 BJS - [19:42:55]: Cannot add more vertex attributes for mesh Shape_average_petite:Body.001
e._LogEnabled @ logger.ts:107Understand this error
logger.ts:107 BJS - [19:42:55]: Unable to compile effect:

Additional Details:
Blender version: 3.6
Operating System: windows10
Browser: Google Chrome
I have also created a video explaining the issue in detail: Video Link
Exporting the model without all shape keys selected (no issue occurs). Reviewing the Babylon.js documentation for potential issues related to shape keys. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
